# Fixing "multiple drivers" errors in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have some code written in Verilog, simulation works well, but synthesis of course (what did I expect?) doesn't. I get an error about multiple drivers being used. Here is the basic code that will cause this error (not real code because that is ~300 lines at this point):

```
always @(posedge reset) begin
   A <= 0;
   B <= 0;
   C <= 0;
   ...
end

always @(posedge D) begin
   case (E)
     0: do something
     1: do something else
     2: begin C <= B; A <= 1; end 
     default: ...
end

always @(posedge A) begin
   B <= 1;
   A <= 0;
end
```

So the idea is I want to have essentially sequential code, but I'm not allowed to mix blocking and non-blocking code, so I have non-blocking statements. C <= B needs to happen before B <= 1, because I want C to have the old value of B. So I figured I would essentially insert a flag in the form of A to make changes to B once C acquired its value.

I don't know how to fix it. I also don't really understand the point of allowing multiple processes to exist at all (especially since simulation gives no warning about this being a problem), if they have to be 100% unrelated.

I understand that it cannot promise that posedge D and posedge A will not happen at the same time, but I know that they won't. Is there a way to tell the compiler that?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't drive a signal (`A`, `B`, `C`) in more than 1 `always` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that it cannot promise that posedge D and posedge A will
>   not happen at the same time, but I know that they won't.

Yes, but like you said, the compiler doesn't know that, and will complain. You have to make sure that you are not driving variables from multiple always blocks.

To do this, use case statements. For example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin // or some common condition
  case (reset)
    0:
    // do stuff, and use nested case statements
    1:
    // reset
    ...
end
```

And just in case you don't know, you want to use case statements instead of if statements because the compiler can optimize the code better with case statements.

Comment: But I need it to react on the rising edge of D. I don't know how to put that into if statements, nevermind case... D spans multiple clock cycles, but I want only a single reaction to occur during the entire pulse. Do you know how to do that? Should I just compare the state constantly to what it used to be, and if it changed react?

Comment: Yes you should "compare the state constantly to what it used to be, and if it changed react". You can have a variable D_n (or D next) and update it in an always comb block. Then your case statement will be case (D==1  && D!=D_n).